# How to create a tableView with multiple column structure and horizontal scroll in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, gridview, ios4

In my iPhone app, I am having a requirement of putting a tableView that is similar to GridView.

How can we create and implement it?

Comment: some sort of Excel-like viewer?

Comment: @mga:Thanks for the input!. ya exactly. What can be done?

Comment: Use **UIScrollView** for *horizontal scroll* and **custom UIViews** for *multiple column structure*.

Comment: @Simon: So do you mean that normal tableview is not to be used? Because if it is so, then how can I manage my rows?

Comment: Thanks Simon!! Your comment has helped.!! Please specify the same as an answer so that I can accept it and it can be useful to others who are trying to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon mentioned... I don't think a tableView would be the best options for this.

I would use a UIScrollView. Allow for both horiz and vert scrolling. This will allow you to pan around any direction. you could even add snapping to have the scroll view always stop at the edge of cells so you don't wind up with a lot of half cells on the display.

tableViews would be a create model though. Everything from the display calls to creating (using a re-use pool) is all there in tableView and could be adapted to use a grid.